# Sanitizing file paths represented as strings across platforms in python

Tags: python

I work on a model which has a .csv input sheet, one of my colleagues (on windows) might save a path in this .csv input sheet such as `A_Inputs\inputs\sets\modeledyears_set.csv`.

Another colleague (on mac) might save a path in the .csv input sheet such as `A_Inputs/inputs/sets/other_modeledyears_set.csv`.

When I go to run this input sheet on our linux server, the windows entered path looks like `A_Inputs\\inputs\\sets\\modeledyears_set.csv`, and the mac entered path looks like `A_Inputs/inputs/sets/other_modeledyears_set.csv`.

Normally, I could split either path into its components and save into a universally accessible path with `os.path.join(windows_path.split('\\'))` or `os.path.join(unix_path.split('/'))`,

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to get a `os.path.join()` result without performing both of these splits.

Is there some `os` function that will sanitize a path represented as a string, regardless of the direction the slashes face? I'm trying to avoid if/else logic based on the users operating system.

Comment: How about doing ```unknown_path.replace("\\", "/")```. Since "\" is not a valid posix path character you shouldn't have to worry about invalidating any ```unix_path```. Also you won't have to do split at all after this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing both paths, you can use the following to support both `Unix` and `Windows`

```
import os
os.path.join(path.split(os.pathsep))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize `os.path.sep` and `os.sep` exist. I ended up combining this with @Mslimmer's suggestion to `.replace`. Using `unknown_path.replace('\\', os.sep).replace('/', os.sep)`